# Forcing AngularJS directive to link outside digest cycle

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This refers to an Angular 1 application.

If the DOM is modified outside the context of my angular application, I know I can use `angular.element(document.body).scope().$apply()` to force the whole app to re-render, including the newly injected content.

However my directives never seem to link.

So in the example below, the markup `<message></message>`  should render `Hello World`, but when it is injected manually, then digest applied, the `link` method never appears to run.

https://jsbin.com/wecevogubu/edit?html,js,console,output

javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.directive('message', function() {
  return {
    template: 'Hello, World!',
    link: function() {
      console.log('message link')
    }
  }
})

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<message>default content</message>'
  var scope = window.angular.element(document.body).scope()
  scope.$apply()
})
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  inside app:
  <message></message>

  outside app:
  <button id="button">Print another message</button>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your idea that $apply forces the whole app to re-render, including the newly injected content is erroneous. $apply only triggers all the watchers and their listening functions if there is any change detected. Those changes will update the DOM for directives that have been previously compiled. $apply will not compile and link new directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, you can do this with [angular.injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector)

> `angular.injector` allows you to inject and compile some markup after the application has been bootstrapped

So the code for your example could be:

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var $directive = $('<message>default message</message>');
  $('#content').append($directive);

  angular.element(document.body).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
    var scope = angular.element($directive).scope();
    $compile($directive)(scope);
  });
})
```

[image]

Hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: I believe this has the correct answer, but I also think `$compile` is the key here and injector is almost irrelevant to the question and should not be the focus here.  You could for example put your directive in a scope where the controller does: `$scope.compile = $compile;` and then from the outside `document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = scope.compile("<message>...</message>")(scope)[0].innerHTML`.

Comment: @ippi thanks for pointing this out, as you mentioned `$compile` is the key here and `injector` is a way to access it from the outside.

Comment: Be aware that compiling adds watchers to scope. Without a plan to remove those watchers when removing elements from the DOM, the code will develop memory leaks.

Comment: thanks guys this is exactly what I was looking for! Funnily enough I have actually used exactly this in the past, and apparently forgot about it.